# Is it possible to fill an Othello/Reversi board with one color?

Tags: othello

I have a simple question, but couldn't find an answer anywhere: is it possible to fill an Othello/Reversi board with one color?
I already played some games where one of the two opponents was wiped out, but in these case the board was never filled. It is possible to wipe out your opponent on the last move?

Comment: I found a game theory link here: http://math.duke.edu/~bray/Courses/49s/StudentSurveys/Fall2014/KL_Paper2_GameTheoryOfReversi.pdf but no direct answer to that question

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

Here is a youtube link showing a game where black fills the entire board:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=prWG1OFgVqg&t=0m30s

(the game starts at 30s)

Comment: I've tried a dozen or so games versus myself and couldn't pull this off if I wanted to. Nice find.

Comment: I've had it happen *to* me once, and *from* me once: no clue how to reproduce it *intentionally*, though :)

Comment: Unfortunately this video no longer exists.